# What is the format of the youtube-dl configuration file?

Tags: youtube-dl

Can't find it anywhere. I do know it goes in `/etc/youtube-dl.conf` or `~/.config/youtube-dl/config`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no format.  Just put the command line options in the file, e.g.`--extract-audio --no-mtime`

[Source](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#configuration)

So one line per configuration option, for example to change the default directory keeping the standard file name, just this line would be needed:

```
-o '~/Downloads/%(title)s-%(id)s.%(ext)s'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
w3@aardvark:~(0)$ apt-cache search youtube-dl
youtube-dl - downloader of videos from YouTube and other sites
nicovideo-dl - Download videos from www.nicovideo.jp
w3@aardvark:~(0)$ dpkg -l !$
dpkg -l youtube-dl
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
    ||/ Name                                  Version                 Architecture            Description
+++-=====================================-=======================-=======================-================================================================================
ii  youtube-dl                            2014.02.17-1            all                     downloader of videos from YouTube and other sites
w3@aardvark:~(0)$ dpkg -L !$
dpkg -L youtube-dl
/.
/etc
/etc/bash_completion.d
/etc/bash_completion.d/youtube-dl.bash-completion
```

And so forth - listing all the files in the `youtube-dl` package, including,

```
 /usr/share/man/man1/youtube-dl.1.gz
```

And, if you read `man youtube-dl` it will tell you:

```
CONFIGURATION
       You  can  configure  youtube-dl  by  placing  default  arguments  (such  as  --extract-audio --no-mtime  to  always  extract the audio and not copy the mtime) into
       /etc/youtube-dl.conf and/or ~/.config/youtube-dl.conf.  On Windows, the  configuration  file  locations  are  %APPDATA%\youtube-dl\config.txt  and  C:\Users\<Your‐
       name>\youtube-dl.conf.
```